# Java 8 & Spring MVC : Error "404 not found" solved when removing the constants interface. What is the problem?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class containing a GET method. When I try to call it with Postman, I get a 404 not found error. **However if I remove the "implements SubscriptionConstants"   and I call it with the exact same request, everything is OK (status code 200).**

Here is the class where I get the 404 error:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody; 
// other imports

@Controller
@Measured(canStartRootStack = true)
public class AlertsResource extends AbstractResource implements SubscriptionConstants {


    @Autowired
    private SubscriptionSubscriberService subscriptionSubscriberService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/alerts/{triggerid}/subscribers", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<SubscriptionSubscriber> loadSubscribers(@PathVariable final String triggerid) {
        return subscriptionSubscriberService.getSubscribers(triggerid);
    }
 
   // other methods...

    }
```

And here is the request I use with Postman in both cases :

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/resource/alerts/repository%3Acfg%23b02173a8-9b8a-4d4f-b6b0-5df427286d87/subscribers?noCache=4fc0a0c1-7f52-4eea-854d-ef4084eaac71
```

SubscriptionConstants is an interface but it contains only constants such as :

```
String  USER                            = "user";
String  LOGIN                           = "login";
```

Here is the mvc-servlet.xml file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        ">

    <!-- Sub Context used for Rest services -->

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp.webapp.resource" />
    <context:property-placeholder/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jsonObjectMapper"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

Here is an extract of the web.xml file :

```
<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com/mycompany/myapp/webapp/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also checked the xml security files, the non-working class doesn't have a specific security parameter.

What could be the problem ?

**UPDATE :** I solved the 404 error by removing "implements SubscriptionConstants" and by using imports instead of implementing the constants interface, for example :

```
import static com.mycompany.myapp.service.alert.subscription.constants.SubscriptionConstants.USER;
```

But I still don't know why "implements SubscriptionConstants" leads to a 404 error.

When there still was the "implements SubscriptionConstants" I checked the logs when starting the Tomcat server, I found no error in the logs and nothing with the keywords "controller" or "AlertsResource" or "SubscriptionConstants"

Comment: are both the files under same package. If possible, can you share screenshot of project structure. one reason can be that one of the file is in a package that is not getting scanned. may be because of not being child to main application package

Comment: can you post how the controllers are mapped..

Comment: yes both files are in the same package

Comment: Please share the import statement of Controller annotation from the class where this fails.

Comment: @JamesJithin I added the imports in my post

Comment: Thanks @KateL.Few other points 1. ComponentScan config 2. Adding a simple mapping works? 3. Enable Spring Logs to see if mapping is happening

Comment: Moreover, from where does '/resource' comes in place in the URL?

Comment: @JamesJithin I edited my post, not sure if that replies to your questions though.

Comment: Please confirm the package structure as in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1__F0FtOe6HY8hR4T0haS93_V_wHdB2R5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I edited my post with more details on where the problem may come from

Comment: When you had the `implements` and got 404, did you check the log file to see if there were errors starting the webapp? My theory is that Spring failed to load the `@Controller` class, so there was no `@RequestMapping`, which is why you got 404 Not Found.

Comment: @Andreas I updated the end of my post to reply to your question